# Do CosmosDB Mongo API compound unique indexes require each field to be unique?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, unique-constraint, node-mongodb-native, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi, compound-index

I'm trying to set up a collection of versioned documents in which I insert a new document with the same id and a timestamp whenever there's an edit operation. I use a unique compound index for this on the id and timestamp fields. CosmosDB is giving me `MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error` whenever I try to insert a document with a different id but an identical timestamp to another document. The MongoDB documentation says that I should be able to do this:

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/core/index-unique/#unique-compound-index

> You can also enforce a unique constraint on compound indexes. If you use the unique constraint on a compound index, then MongoDB will enforce uniqueness on the combination of the index key values.

I tried using a non-unique index but the Resource Manager template failed, saying that non-unique compound indexes are not supported. I'm using the node.js native driver `v3.2.4`. I also tried to use Azure Portal to insert documents but received the same error. This makes me believe it's not a problem between CosmosDB and the node.js driver.

Here's a small example to demonstrate the problem. I'm running it with Node `v10.15.3`.

```js
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const mongoUrl = process.env.COSMOSDB_CONNECTION_STRING;
const collectionName = 'indextest';

const client = new MongoClient(mongoUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true });
let connection;

const testIndex = async () => {
  const now = Date.now();
  connection = await client.connect();
  const db = connection.db('master');
  await db.collection(collectionName).drop();
  const collection = await db.createCollection(collectionName);
  await collection.createIndex({ id: 1, ts: -1 }, { unique: true });
  await collection.insertOne({ id: 1, ts: now, title: 'My first document' });
  await collection.insertOne({ id: 2, ts: now, title: 'My other document' });
};

(async () => {
  try {
    await testIndex();
    console.log('It works');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    await connection.close();
  }
})();
```

I would expect the two insert operations to work and for the program to exit with `It works`. What I get instead is an Error:

```js
{ MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: master.indextest Failed _id or unique key constraint
    at Function.create (/home/node/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:43:12)
    at toError (/home/node/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:149:22)
    at coll.s.topology.insert (/home/node/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/collection_ops.js:859:39)
    at handler (/home/node/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/replset.js:1155:22)
    at /home/node/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:397:18
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
  driver: true,
  name: 'MongoError',
  index: 0,
  code: 11000,
  errmsg:
   'E11000 duplicate key error collection: master.indextest Failed _id or unique key constraint',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Is this expected behavior or a bug in CosmosDB's MongoDB API?